# renaming a file while creating zip file through Maven-assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

i am using **maven-assembly** plugin to **create the zip** , how can i **rename** some files while zipping using the same plugin??

**Update:**

This is the profile in pom

```
    <profile>
        <id>D1</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>D1</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>               
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>assembly/online-distribution.D1.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

This is Assembly.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly- 
    plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<id>online</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>resources</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>${project.groupId}:core-config:jar</include>
        </includes>
        <unpackOptions>
            <includes>
            <include>coresrv/env-config.D1.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
    <files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.groupId}/core-config.jar/coresrv/env-config.D1.properties</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <destName>env-config.properties</destName>
    </file>
</files>
</assembly>
```

i am getting that jar and unpacking it, then renaming a file and zipping it again.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the pom file and the descriptor which you are using?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i have updated.

Comment: Are you sure your descriptor is correct, cause it looks wrong (dependencySet) without dependencySets. You don't have a warning? Furthermore why don't you use an up-to-date version of the maven-assembly-plugin (2.4).

Comment: every thing is working fine except renaming.Is there any way to rename the a file of dependency while unpacking it ??

Comment: I've got my doubts that there is no error/warning message during the run. But i've given an answer to your question.

Comment: I've checked the descriptor and it has errors. The *dependencySet* is **not allowed to be alone** at that level. It must be a child of **dependencySets**.

Comment: how can i rename "env-config.D1.properties" to "env-config.properties" in above assembly.xml or in pom.xml ??

Comment: Doesn't do the destName the trick? If not I would first update the version of maven-assembly-plugin to 2.4 furthermore check the output during the build (WARNINGs!) and recheck the descriptor, cause it produces errors in Eclipse based on XSD checks. Apart from that how do you call the maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: hi again, i got the wt u told..but thing is i am having the dependency called "core-config.jar" that has "env-config.D1.properties".i want to rename that properties file to "env-config.properties". how can i do it ?? (refer assembly.xml) i am trying to rename it through file but not happening.. :(

Comment: is there any maven plugin that can be used for unzipping , then renaming the zipped files and zipping back the dependencies ??(Other than maven assembly and ant plugin)

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
 <outputFileNameMapping>...</outputFileNameMapping>
```

which sets the mapping pattern for all dependencies included in this assembly uses

default value:

```
${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}.
```

Comment: Also works inside dependencySet elements, if only some dependencies shall be renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Answering an old post for posterity... and next time I ask Google and get sent here.

Renaming used to be a pain in Maven, this plugin does what is says on the tin:

[copy-rename-maven-plugin](http://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/)

(available in [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccopy-rename-maven-plugin))

Easy to use:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-properties-file</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceFile>source.props</sourceFile>
                        <destinationFile>destination.properties</destinationFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Note: the `rename` goal will move file(s) in target/

Answer (score 2):

I faced with same problem, I need to use unpack with renaming some files and as solution we can use two executions of maven-assembly-plugin.

During first execution we will use format `dir` instead of one of archive formats and will prepare files content and as result will have folder with all needed files.

During second execution we will use folder from previous execution as source in `fileSets` with `files` and we will have ability to rename any file using `files.file.destName`, and as format for second execution we can use archive format like `zip` to create final archive.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add it in assembly plugin executions like below;

```
<executions>
 <execution>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>  you can give any name you want  <finalName>
  <configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: You might also need `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697144/can-not-set-the-final-jar-name-with-maven-assembly-plugin