# Can not set the final jar name with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

This is how I configured `maven-assembly-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.myapp.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <!--
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and I expect the final jar file should be `myapp.jar` but it ends up with `myapp-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Can you tell me how to configure to exclude `"jar-with-dependencies"` out of the final name?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You can specify the `finalName` property to give the jar the name you want, and specify that `appendAssemblyId` should be false to avoid the `jar-with-dependencies` suffix.
The configuration below will output a jar called `test.jar`

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.myapp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
               <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

Comment: you also should uncomment `<descriptorRefs>` thing, otherwise you'll get something like that:  `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:attached (default) on project ...: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.`

Comment: Excellent `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` this line is necessary .

Comment: The tag "finalName" is not in assembly plugin v3.x

Comment: But that produces a `[WARNING] Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing`

Comment: @isapir, I googled for a solution and it appears that this _works as documented_.   See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-824.  It also referenced http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_assembly, where the id field says *Sets the id of this assembly. This is a symbolic name for a particular assembly of files from this project. Also, aside from being used to distinctly name the assembled package by attaching its value to the generated archive, the id is used as your artifact's classifier when deploying*.  I still don't fully understand it.

Comment: Here is the actual _works as documented_ change. http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1754566, it is referenced in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-824 (link in my previous comment).

Comment: The described solution doesn't work for me with plugin v2.4 nor v2.2.2, for example. Tested with Maven 3.3.9. Moreover, it seems like the possibility of setting name of the resultant assembly artifact was removed in 3.x altogether - see [How to set final jar name with maven-assembly-plugin version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101044/how-to-set-final-jar-name-with-maven-assembly-plugin-version-3). Altogether, this maven plugin is very confusing.