# How to set final jar name with maven-assembly-plugin version 3

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

In older versions of the plugin you could use `<finalName>`, but that does not exist any more.
At the moment I am getting projectName-version-jar-with-dependencies.jar and it would be nice to change this.

Comment: Why do you say it's not working / doesn't exist any more? I'm using assembly plugin version 3.0.0 (i.e. latest), and `finalName` is working just fine.

Comment: I am saying it is not there any more because it is not in the list of parameters http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html

Comment: Aha ok I see - I just added `<finalName>` to the `<configuration>` part and my IDE is reporting an error, because it is not allowed they according to the ddt, but it is still working. So it is a kind of undocumented, hidden feature.

Comment: Probably some sort of bug. I can't imagine you'd want to drop such an important feature and replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `finalName` parameter is set in the project build section and not in the plugin configuration.

so essentially:

```
<build>
   <finalName>xyz</finalName>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        ....
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

The assembly plugin gets the final name from reading the property `${project.build.finalName}` and is a readonly parameter.

At least that´s what the code says: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-assembly-plugin-3.0.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java?view=markup

Comment: Now I see - that was the part that I was missing. There should be a hint in the documentation for the assembly plugin how to use it correct.

Comment: 2021 -- I tried this and it changed the name of ALL jars in the build. That's probably why they pulled it from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-module project, I created the assemblies in each module. To change the name I used a new child module called 'assembly' and I collected all the single module assemblies into a new directory. At that point, you can change the output name. I am following this FAQ https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#module-binaries

My final assembly (collection of all module assemblies look like this):

```
<assembly>
    <id>final</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <moduleSets>
      <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <binaries>
            <attachmentClassifier>jar-with-dependencies</attachmentClassifier>
            <outputDirectory>dist/${module.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
        </binaries>
      </moduleSet>
    </modulesSets>
</assembly>
```

This should allow you to change the artifact name for the assembly file only.